# No Resource found that matchces the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog' in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I tried to change the Target Framework Version, Target Compile version. Even though getting same errors. How can I solve this issue in VS 2017, Xamarin.Forms with latest version?

[image]

Comment: Try closing you project, delete obj and bin folder,  and then rebuild again. Let me know if it worked.

Comment: Yeah , I have tried with this also. Eventhough I was getting same error. I have done that:"Uninstalled latest version of Xamarin.Forms & used older version of Xamarin.Forms . Then it worked for me."

Comment: A bitmap screenshot of your errors is not enough to help readers help you. We need a [mcve]. That probably means: (1) the error(s) you are getting in text format, (2) the code that causes them, (3) what you have done so far to research this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the theme in Style File of your Xamarin.Android.
You Can Find Style.Xml in Xamarin.Android -> Resource -> values -> style.xml

define your theme you want to use or you can use the default theme

Comment: Nope, I think Not becuase of this reason. I have n't touched styles.xml . Finally, I have deleted that project. and Recreated new one. Anyway Thank you.